# Row wise average return nan

Tags: pandas, row, mean

[Here is my data frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O4LHt.png)

Where I wrote 1 or 2, I would like to get the mean/median of the previous column.
For instance, for DXC.N, the expected output where I wrote 1 is mean(nan,(-0.44..),0.1127..,(-0.15..),(-0.19..),nan))
For EFX, the expected output where I wrote 2 is mean(nan,-0,14..,0.06..,0.13..,0.007,nan)
I tried the following but it returns only nans :

```
DF['Column8']=DF.groupby('Column1')['Column8'].mean()
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need something more like this:

You want the mean of colum7, not column8 right?

```
# use transform() as it will return a series of values that will match in legnth to your original dataframe
DF['Column8']=DF.groupby('Column1')['Column7'].transform('mean')
```

Comment: Sorry Yes, of column 7!